# Internet Explorer PDF Reader

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf

I apologize for the length of this question, but some background explanation is required.

**Background:**

I'm working on an internal web application that will display a pdf in an iframe.  Adobe Reader X offers a "Read Mode" for displaying the pdf in the browser.  This removes the shell and adds a menu box to the bottom of the pdf when the mouse is over the "middle center".  In versions prior to X you could use JavaScript to modify the toolbar menu items.

**What I Need:**

I need to display the pdf in "Read Mode" AND remove all menu items.  The computers that are to run this app are basically a kiosk and are literally a computer, monitor and mouse.  No printers, no keyboard, no other interactivity.

My question is this:
How can I load a pdf for reading in internet explorer, and disable all interaction except scrolling.  That is, no menus, no context menu, and no "shadow bar" when the bottom center is moused over.  I've been searching for alternatives to Adobe, and there are some great ones, but the ones I've found that have a browser plugin, do not have a plugin for IE.

If someone know a way to just load the PDF Contents that would be an even better route.

**More Information:**

If it helps, while this is being built for Internet Explorer, the web-page will be loaded into a windows form that is just a full-screen browser control.

**Other things I've tried:**

I have also tried positioning a transparent iFrame on top of the pdf iFrame, covering only the displayed content, but leaving the scrollbars intact.  This worked perfect if I loaded anything BUT a pdf.  If I loaded any other website then it worked as expected (except the scroll wheel of course doesn't scroll the webpage).  If a pdf was loaded, then all that would appear is a white square.  Use the dev toolbar to remove the transparent iFrame and the PDF looks good.

Comment: I've added the C#, JavaScript, and Html tags because there might be a solution using any or all of these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have come up with a final solution.

**Needs:**

1. Load PDF in iFrame in "Reader Mode" but with no shadow bar
2. PDF Context Menu should be disabled

Addressing the first need is easy with some caveats.  Set the source of the iFrame to "pathToPdf/document.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0".  The caveats here are that (in IE at least) once this breaks, then the browser needs to be closed and re-opened to work again.  So, what can break it?

- User right clicks and opens the navigation pane buttons.
- User presses the escape button on the keyboard.

The webpage is loaded into the browser control of a windows form, and luckily once broken there it works fine without closing and reopening.  Could still be a problem though for the PDF being viewed.  I don't have to worry about the escape key, because the app is running on a KIOSK(basically) and there is no keyboard, only a mouse.

Disabling the context menu has proved to be the most difficult thing to do.  The web browser control has a "IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled" property that when set to "False" will disable the context menu for the browser.  Probably because the adobe reader is a plugin, this does not effect the PDF.  With Reader X there is no registry setting (that I could find) or JavaScript method, or general setting that will disable context menu.

I was ready to give up when I remembered something.  This is a kiosk, and there is no need for the right mouse button.  So the solution; modify the registry and turn off the right click for the internal OS.  To do that simply open regedit and goto:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
- Find (or create if it is not there) a DWORD key named "NoViewContextMenu".
- A value of 1 will disable right clicking, 0 will enable.

**Summary:**

1. Use "pathToPdf/document.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0"
2. Disable right click in windows registry

**Edit:**

The registry hack only disables the right mouse button in windows explorer.  We are having no luck in finding a good software solution, so we are left with either writing our own custom mouse drivers or simply popping open the mice and removing the physical trigger mechanism.

Comment: In testing I have discovered that the registry hack only disables right click for windows explorer.  It does not disable the right mouse button system wide...I will update again when I have a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a good partial solution.  A product called [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com).

Using it, I can add the following JavaScript to my page:

```
function embedPDF() {
        var myPDF = new PDFObject({
            url: 'PathToPdf.pdf',
            pdfOpenParams: { 
                scrollbars: '1',
                toolbar: '0',
                statusbar: '0',
                messages: '0', 
                navpanes: '0' 
            }
        }).embed('DivToLoadPdfInto');
    }

    window.onload = embedPDF;
```

This will embed the pdf into a div and remove the toolbar, statusbar, message, navpanes, but still allow scrollbars.  This prevents the shadow box menu from appearing, which is great!

Users can still right-click on the pdf so I'll try the standard Right-Click blockers in JavaScript and edit if I can get something to work.

**Edit:**

A good resource for URL Parameters can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf).

Comment: PDFObject's website is also a great resource to determine the features that Adobe Reader is capable of. The Javascript file is not even necessary, you can just use their guide to create the embed code that you need.

Comment: I was looking into doing just that, using the PDFObject site as a resource.  One problem I discovered though is it doesn't eliminate the shadow box, it moves it from the bottom to the top of the window...

Comment: Yeah, and I don't think you'll be able to avoid that.  Adobe Reader's options are limited.